# A question concerning the integral of a nonnegative function

Tags: measure-theory

I have been struggling with the following problem. In fact, there are several problems similar to this one that are also giving me trouble. Hence, I have some misunderstanding, or I am lacking some technique. I have included some of my ideas after stating the problem.

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $(X,\textbf{X},\mu)$ be a measure space. If $f$ is a nonnegative function and $\int f\>d\mu < \infty$, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a set $E \in \textbf{X}$ such that $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $$\int f d\mu \leq \int_{E} f\>d\mu + \epsilon.$$

$\textbf{ Ideas:}$ Taking sets like $E_n = \{x \in X: f(x)\geq n\}$ or $E_n = \{x \in X: f(x) \geq 1/n\}$ initially came to my mind since I know I can show that these sets have finite measure. (In the former set, for instance, because $n\chi_{E_n} \leq f$, $n\mu(E_n) \leq \int f\>d\mu < \infty.$) From here, unfortunely, my tinerking around with these sets have proved unfruitful. A small hint, hopefully, will get the wheels in motion! Thank You!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E_t=\{f\leqslant t\}$ and $f_t=f\cdot\mathbf 1_{E_t}$. Then $f_t\leqslant f$, $f$ is integrable and $f_t\to f$ when $t\to\infty$, hence the integrals of $f_t$ and $f$ can be made as close as one wants. Now, identify the integral of $f_t$.

If the measure of $E_t$ is finite, the task is over. Otherwise, consider $E_{s,t}=\{s\leqslant f\leqslant t\}$ and show this fits if $s$ is small enough.

Comment: I'm revisiting this question and I'm wondering if using $E_n = \{x \in X: f(x) \geq 1/n\}$ would work. Specifically, the monotone increasing sequence $(f\chi_{E_{n}})$ of non-negative functions converges pointwise to $f$. The Monotone Convergence Theorem implies that we can the integrals of $f\chi_{E_{n}}$ and $f$ as close as we want. So, I would end up putting our desired $E$ equal to $E_{N}$ for large enough $N$. Would this work too? Thank you.

Comment: It seems so. $ $